# Total memory usage as reported by kubectl top nodes vs top pods

Tags: kubernetes

Consider these two commands run against my cluster.

First roll up all known used ram as reported by `top nodes`:

```
$ kubectl --no-headers=true top nodes | awk 'BEGIN { total=0 } { total+=$4 } END { print total, "Mi" }'
504972 Mi
```

Then by all pods in `top pods`

```
phs@anvil:~$ kubectl --no-headers=true --all-namespaces=true top pods |  awk 'BEGIN { total=0 } { total+=$4 } END { print total, "Mi" }'
163503 Mi
```

I've already confirmed that all living pods appear in `top pods`.

What is with the huge discrepancy?  Where does the extra ram go?

Answer (score 3):

It appears the difference comes down to `buffers`. If we run `free -mw` on each node I can see significant (10-15 GB) amounts of ram sunk there.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o name | cut -d / -f 2 | while read node; do ssh -n admin@$node 'free -mw | fgrep Mem:'; done | awk 'BEGIN { total=0 } { total+=$6 } END { print total, "Mi" }'
278815 Mi
```

Their total is approximately the missing mount (these commands were run at different times, and so exact equality shouldn't be expected.)